# In IE my drop down menus are actually dropping right. How can I fix this?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I just installed drop down menus on my website: http://www.squeakybooks.com/ On Mozilla they work like a dream. I haven't had a chance to check safari or Chrome yet, but in IE the drop down menus actually drop to the right. This is a HUGE pain because when you try to click on something in the drop down menu, it'll make the NEXT drop down menu activate even farther to the right.

However, it does work on this website: http://squeakytestblog.blogspot.com/ Even though I uploaded the exact same .xml file to both.

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
#jsddm {
width:960px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
z-index:1000000000;
position:relative;
left:5%
}

#jsddm li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
font: 12px Tahoma, Arial;
}

#jsddm li a {
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
margin:0px 0px;
border: 0px solid #AAAAAA;
background: #;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#), to(#));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #, #);
padding: 2px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
text-shadow: #ffffff 0 0px 0;
color: #363d1b;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
text-style: center;
}

#jsddm li a:hover {
background: #;
}

#jsddm li ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
border: 1px solid black;
text-style: center;
}

#jsddm li ul li {
float: none;
display: inline;
}

#jsddm li ul li a {
width: auto;
background: #96CDCD;
}

#jsddm li ul li a:hover {
background: #D3DC6E;
}
```

I followed this tutorial: allblogtools.com/tricks-and-hacks/add-beautiful-drop-down-menu-for-blogger/

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Your submenu does not have any point of reference from where to load from, to fix it you can define your list menu item as relative and position your submenu absolutely to the `left` of the menu item being hovered. Try this:

**CSS**

```
#jsddm li {
    float: left;
    font: 12px Tahoma,Arial;
    list-style: none outside none;
    position: relative;
}

#jsddm li ul {
    border: 1px solid black;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```